# Alexa skill async await fetching data from DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, async-await, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

The following code is my launch handler in my Alexa skill and I have a variable named x inside of my handler. I am trying to set x to data that I'm getting from dynamoDB and to use it outside of the get function (I got the function from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.02) so that Alexa can speak the value (a string) of x (as you see in the return). The statement in my "get" function is not changing the value of x outside of the get function itself. I know that the x inside of the get function is actually being changed because I am logging it to console. So I posted a similar post on this, and I initially thought it was a scoping issue, but turns out it's because the get function is asynchronous. Hence, I added the async and await keywords as shown below. I'm new to NodeJS so that's where I thought I should put them, according to what I've researched. This is still not working however.

```
const LaunchHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === `LaunchRequest`;
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    var x;

    //DYNAMO GET FUNCTION
    await DBClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
         x = data.Item.Answer;
    } }); 

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(x)
      .withShouldEndSession(false)
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

As a side note, here's the JSON that I'm (successfully) returning from the database:

```
{
    "Item": {
        "Answer": "Sunny weather",
        "Question": "What is the weather like today"
    }
}
```

Comment: The `.get()` method seems to be accepting a callback so you'd have to wrap it in an explicit `Promise` to make it work well with `async/await`. But from a quick look at the docs, looks like appending a `.promise()` at the end of your method should return a `Promise` so I'd try that first and see if it works. Something along the lines of `.get(params).promise()`

Comment: Thank you very much this did it!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? Within the handle function i call another function getSpeechOutput to create some feedback text. Thus function calls the dynamodb function getGA to get user data

```
const getSpeechOutput = async function (version) {
  const gadata = await ga.getGA(gaQueryUsers, 'ga:users')

  let speechOutput;
  ...
  return ...
}

const UsersIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'UsersIntent';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    try {
      let speechOutput
     ...
        speechOutput = await getSpeechOutput("long");
     ...

      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speechOutput)
        .reprompt("Noch eine Frage?")
        .withSimpleCard(defaulttext.SKILL_NAME, speechOutput)
        .getResponse();

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
};
```

Thats the db function:

```
const getUser = async function (userId) {
    const dynamodbParams = {
        TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE_BLICKANALYTICS,
        Key: {
            id: userId
        }
    }
    return await dynamoDb.get(dynamodbParams).promise()
}
```